# Having trouble with grid spacing using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a back end developer trying to get my front end skills up to par.  I am following a video tutorial on building a portfolio site using bootstrap- but I have hit a snag.  I have triple-checked my code, and even started the lesson over to try and see if it was just some dumb error on my part (it very well could be).

My photos should be in a grid that is 3 columns wide.  Unfortunately,the images are showing up as 2 columns and two rows, and the spacing seems off (there is too much).

Here is the HTML in question.  I have included the pill navigation code as well, in case it is relevant.

```
<div class="container-fluid filterable-portfolio">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="portfolio-title">Filter by:</li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">School Projects</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Personal Projects</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Unity Projects</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">etc.</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row portfolio-items">

        <figure class="portfolio-item col-sm-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/400" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class="portfolio-item col-sm-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/400" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class="portfolio-item col-sm-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/400" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class="portfolio-item col-sm-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/400" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class="portfolio-item col-sm-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/400" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class="portfolio-item col-sm-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/400" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        </figure>

    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS code- not sure if this is the problem, but I figure more information couldn't hurt.

```
.portfolio-title{
padding: 10px 15px 10px 0;
font-weight: bold;
}
.nav-pills>li.active>a, .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus {       
background: #111;
color: #f5f5f5;
}

.nav-pills a{
color: #f5f5f5;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus {
background: none;
}

.portfolio-item {
margin-bottom: 1rem;    
}

.portfolio-item img {
-webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
filter:grayscale(100%);
border-radius:6px;
}

.portfolio-item:hover img {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(50%);
filter: grayscale(50%);
}

.filterable-portfolio{
margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.portfolio-item img{    
width :100%;    
}
```

Any help with this would be GREATLY appreciated.  I really want to understand what exactly I am doing wrong.  Thanks much for taking the time to help with this!

Comment: what is the issue? https://jsfiddle.net/ceLbses9/1/

Comment: Interesting- it looks great in jsfiddle, but on my site, the issue persists.  I wonder why?  Here is a link to view what I am seeing on my end- http://imgur.com/a/V1CmN

Comment: check for extra margins...

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Just thought that I would share my solution with you- my load order was all out of whack.  I fixed the grid issue, but another popped up... I think I am going to start from scratch and use what I have learned to avoid the same mistakes.  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<div class="container-fluid filterable-portfolio">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="portfolio-title">Filter by:</li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">School Projects</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Personal Projects</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Unity Projects</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">etc.</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row portfolio-items">
        <figure class="portfolio-item col-sm-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/400" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        </figure>
        <figure class="portfolio-item col-sm-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/400" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        </figure>
        <figure class="portfolio-item col-sm-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/400" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        </figure> 
        </div>
        </div>
```

you used 6 photos thats why it takes 2 rows.if you want 6 photos is a grid that it will 2 column each...because a single grid has 12 columns...hope it helps

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing that, and the results are two images in row 1 and 1 image in row 2.  In a comment above, using jsfiddle and my code, it looks like it works- so the issue must be with something else with my site.  Just not sure what yet.